# How to have search results page sorted by post date

Tags: search, date-time

On this search results page:
http://p2reloaded.com/?s=versions&search-submit=Search

I'd like to inverse the order of the results to start by newest post date first at the top of the page. Right now it's showing older posts first. Is there a way to specify that in the WP search function through a URL parameter?

BTW, I am had to install the Relevanssi plugin to get WP (or the theme?) to search using tags.

Thanks!
Noel

Comment: I've just checked your link, and the newest posts are at the top...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too, it was weird, a few minutes before that the results were showing the opposite order. Not sure what Relevanssi plugin is doing but I kind of need it since the theme's search function wasn't searching tags at all tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress will order search results by newest post first by default, so if your results are in a different order then it looks like another plugin is affecting them.

Have you tried searching with all other plugins disabled?

If you're using Relevanssi, then it won't order results by date as Relvanssia overrides this with its own weighting algorithm instead (which is the whole point of using Relevanssi).